# Overloading indexing operator

Tags: c++, indexing, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the indexing operator `[]`. I have two versions 
and I need to use both of them, but when I build the project one of them is called and I get an error wherever I use the second one: `Invalid operands to binary expression double and Quarters`.

Here's the first one:

```
Quarters& Security :: operator [] (QuarterType quarter){
    return quartersData[static_cast<int>(quarter)];
}
```

and the second one:

```
const double& Security :: operator [] (QuarterType quarter) const{
    return (quartersData[static_cast<int>(quarter)].getPrediction());
}
```

What is the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: *"I get an error wherever I used the second one"*... and that error would be what? And what are the lines of code when you try to call the second one?

Comment: @CoryKramer the error is : Invalid operands to binary expression double and Quarters, and an example of a line is " double x=security[quarterType] "

Comment: @Raw305 Is `security` `const`? If it is `security[quarterType]` will return a `const double&`, but if it *isn't* it will return a `Quarters&`, which is a strange way of overloading. Perhaps you should use a conversion operator overload instead?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that line, as well as a few more lines for context (i.e where `security` and `quarterType` are defined)

Answer (score 2):

Overriding doesn't take into account the return type. Since in both cases the parameter types are the same, overriding takes into account only `const`-ness of the object. If your object is not `const`, then non-const version of `operator[]` will be called, regardless of what you are trying to do next with it.